# O(n^2) vs O (n(logn)^2)

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

Is time complexity `O(n^2)` or `O (n(logn)^2)` better?

I know that when we simplify it, it becomes

```
O(n) vs O((logn)^2)
```

and `logn` < `n`, but what about `logn^2`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**n** is only less than **(*log* n)<sup>2</sup>** for values of **n** less than 0.49...

So in general **(*log* n)<sup>2</sup>** is better for large **n**...

But since these ***O*(something)**-notations always leave out constant factors, in your case it might not be possible to say for sure which algorithm is better...

Here's a graph:

[image]

(The blue line is **n** and the green line is **(*log* n)<sup>2</sup>**)

Notice, how the difference for small values of **n** isn't so big and might easily be dwarfed by the constant factors not included in the Big-O notation.

But for large **n**, **(*log* n)<sup>2</sup>** wins hands down:

[image]

Comment: `Notice how the green line shoots up to infinity for tiny values of n` asymptotics is not about *whether* something goes to infinity, but about how fast it approaches infinity. `log(n)^2` goes to infinity as well.

Comment: @phant0m What I was trying to point out is that `(log n)^2` also goes to infinity for SMALL values of n, not just large ones. But that's more of a purely mathematical observation since n usually isn't less than 1 anyways... I'll get rid of the line. It doesn't really add anything useful...

Answer (score 14):

**For each constant `k` asymptotically `log(n)^k < n`.**

**Proof** is simple, do log on both sides of the equation, and you get:

```
log(log(n))*k < log(n)
```

It is easy to see that asymptotically, this is correct.

---

Semantic note: Assuming here `log(n)^k == log(n) * log(n) * ... * log(n) (k times)` and NOT `log(log(log(...log(n)))..) (k times)` as it is sometimes also used.

Answer (score 3):

```
O(n^2) vs. O(n*log(n)^2)
<=> O(n) vs. O(log(n)^2) (divide by n)
<=> O(sqrt(n)) vs. O(log(n)) (square root)
<=> polynomial vs. logarithmic
```

Logarithmic wins.

Answer (score 0):

`(logn)^2` is also < `n`.

Take an example:

```
 n = 5
 log n = 0.6989....
 (log n)^ 2 = 0.4885..
```

You can see, (long n)^2 is further reduced.

Even if you take any bigger value of n e.g. 100,000,000 , then

```
   log n = 9
   (log n)^ 2 = 81
```

which is far less than `n`.

Comment: log(100) < log(100)^2 (assuming ^2 means log(100)*log(100)), `n==5` is a bad example.

Comment: Try with a million.  log n = 13.8155... , and the square of it is 190.8683... .  Keep in mind that O(some function of N) deals with *large* values of N.

Comment: @amit I took even big number in the example. I was updating the answer already.

Comment: @cHao I already took a bigger number which I think is good enough for example.

Answer (score 0):

(Log n)^2 is better because if you do a variable change n by exp m, then m^2 is better than exp m

Answer (score -1):

O(n(logn)^2) is better (faster) for large n!

take log from both sides:

Log(n^2)=2log(n)

Log(n(logn)^2)=Log(n)+2log(Log(n))=Log(n)+2log(Log(n))

lim n--> infinity [(Log(n)+2log(Log(n)))/2log(n)/]=0.5 (use l'Hôpital's rule)(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule)]

Comment: I believe the OP is after (log(n))^2 and not log(n^2)

Comment: you are rigth: log(n(log(n)^2)=log(n)+log(log(n)^2)=log(n)+2(log(log(n))